# SOLR writes - in case we have to scale

Tags: solr

i have a system that has a service that needs to do the following:
1. Read a document from SOLR
2. If exists, update it according to some logic.
3. If not insert it.

The problem is that the service scales and i can get dirty reads since the time they arrive matters in regards of the content I will write to SOLR

Is there a locking mechanism in SOLR so that if 2 thread grabs the same document from SOLR and one write then the other one will fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, there is. It is explained [here](http://yonik.com/solr/optimistic-concurrency/) for example.

So in your case, you just need to make sure you have the *version* field in your schema, and send the it when needed.